# How to practice with Xpath Match Assertion in SoapUI?

Tags: testing, xpath, match, soapui, assertion

I have tested Contains Assertion without any issues but I don't know how to validate the webservices using Xpath Match Assertion in SoapUI.

Can you please tell me how to workout 'Xpath Match' Assertion in SoapUI?

I'm using JSON requests.

Updated: Please find the attachments

1) My JSON Response
2) Assertion Error message

Please tell me how to validate the identifier and please provide the correct XPath expression and Expected Results

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In XPath expression field you need to insert your XPath expression =) 
And in expected result field you need to insert expected result of applying your XPath expression to response of your request.

For example, if response contains something like this: 
[
   {
      "id": "112",
      "username": "user1",
   },
      {
      "id": "233",
      "username": "user2",
   }
]

and you want to verify, that response contains a user with id = 112,
you need to add in XPath expression //id[text() = '112']  and in expected result - 112

In Soap UI pro you can use graphic wizard for creating XPath Match Assertion.

About XPath basics you can read here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But my JSON response looks like this. From this response, how do I get the Identifier?                        <data contentType="application/SOIBareResponse" contentLength="3532">{ "LiaisonAPIUseCaseView": { "PatientRegistryGetDemographicsQueries": { "PatientRegistryGetDemographicsQueriesResponse":{"LiaisonAPIResponse":{"Message":"Get demographics Operation successful.","Successful":true},"Patient":[{"PatientId":[{"Identifier":"A-1B22F517-239F-4A49-9C31-5014F3C40FF5","NameSpace":"LSN","AssigningAuthorityOID":"2.16.840.1.113883.3.1550.3.1.1.1.1"}]...........]}} } }</data>

Comment: Strange response - xml mixed with json. It is in xml view, isn't it? Can you post here raw view or json? You can change response view by selecting necessary tab on the left of response field

Comment: Here's the pure JSON request: {
    "SampleAPIUseCaseView": {
        "PatientRegistryGetDemographicsQueries": {
            "PatientRegistryGetDemographicsQueriesRequest": {
                "SampleAPIRequest": {
                    "SystemCode": "PRV"
                },
                "PatientId": [
                    {
                        "Identifier": "1-PAT-13-MAY-2013",
                        "NameSpace": "ClientA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: In this case XPath expression //Identifier/text() selects value of Identifier

Comment: Hi Artem Izyumov,  Please look over my updated information and the attachments. Thanks

Comment: In this case it is impossible to access Identifier via XPath. SoapUI usually can convert json response to xml, but in your case it just put all json in CDATA tag. You need to use regexp or common Contains Assertion instead.

Comment: If there was the text 112 in the id node, wouldn't the expected result for `//id[text() = '112']` be `true`, not `112`?